# Is this template<int ...> idea in C++ possible?

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors, fft, ntt

I'm trying to learn to implement `template` in C++. When I am changing my NTT (Number theoretic transform) code into one that uses `template`, which looks like this:

```
template <long long mod> struct NTT{
    int x = 0;
    NTT(){
        long long p = mod-1;
        while(!(p % 2)){
            p >>= 1;
            ++x;
        }       
    }   
    const static long long root_pw = 1 << x;
//(there is a function after this that also needs to read the value 'root_pw')
};

signed main()
{
    NTT<998244353> ntt1;
    vector<long long> a(ntt1::root_pw,0);
}
```

It tells me to make x `static`.

When I do that, it tells me to make x `const`, which beats the reason for x being there in the first place.

I use (GNU C++11) and my complier (Dev-C++ 5.11) set to configure (TDM-GCC 4.9.2 64-bit Release), if it helps.

I really want to make this work, but I don't know how.

This is probably stupidly easy, but just what I'm I missing?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You cannot use non-static data member to initialize static data member. Static data members are initialized long before any object (and therefore non-static members) is created.

Comment: In C++14, constexpr function is mostly easy to write as really similar to regular function. In c++11, it is more tricky because of more restriction...

Comment: Note that GCC is on version 9 and version 10 [can't be far off](https://gcc.gnu.org/develop.html#timeline). If you are permitted, strongly consider upgrading from 4.9.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace the C++14 function

```
template <long long mod>
constexpr int f()
{
    int x = 0;
    long long p = mod-1;
    while(!(p % 2)){
        p >>= 1;
        ++x;
    }       
    return x;
}
```

by the C++11 version:

```
template <long long p>
constexpr int f2()
{
    return p % 2 ? 0 : 1 + f2<p / 2>();
}

template <long long mod>
constexpr int f()
{
    return f2<mod - 1>();
}
```

And so

```
template <long long mod>
struct NTT{
    constexpr static const long long root_pw = 1LL << f<mod>();

};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/44f74534c2f357dc)

Comment: Thank you so much!!!

However, after I do so, it says "ntt1 is not a class, namespace, or enumeration" when I wrote:

NTT<998244353> ntt1;
vector<long long> a (ntt1::root_pw, 0);

Could you help me with this part?

Comment: It should be `ntt1.root_pw` (which is an not usual way to call static method (though an instance)) or `using ntt1 = NTT<998244353>;` (so `ntt1` is an alis type instead of an instance class).